# How can I wrap line and shift those lines upwards while maintaining bottom margin?

Tags: html, css, web, sass

In the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0jjs.jpg), when the text length increases, it shifts upwards as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn6Sy.jpg). How can I bring this effect?

Using "word-wrap" wraps the line to the following line, so that doesn't help.

Here ALBUMTextContainer is used inside the class "album". The position of "count" is not to be disturbed rather the "title" should be shifted upwards if it overflows.

```
.album {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 0 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.ALBUMTextContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000);
  width: 352px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  &_details {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 1.34;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    &_name {
      width: 330px;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 22px;
    }

    &_count {
      color: #ccc;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: normal;
      padding-top: 2px;
    }
  }
}

<div className="ALBUMTextContainer">
   <div className="ALBUMTextContainer_details">
     <div className="ALBUMTextContainer_details_name">{title} </div>
     <div className="ALBUMTextContainer_details_count">{count}</div>
   </div></div>
```

Comment: Please provide html/css code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: updated. @Anuresh@Paulie_D

Answer (score 0):

Set `height:auto;`

```
.ALBUMTextContainer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000);
        width: 352px;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```